# Probability that a randomly chose poker hand has at least one Ace

Tags: probability

I just want to check the answer.

Is it

$$\large1- \frac{\binom{48}{13}}{\binom{52}{13}}?$$

It is neither homework nor exam. I am just doing review for probability and I found this question online and I tried to solve it.

Comment: A standard poker hand has $5$ cards. The general idea is right, but it should be $\binom{48}{5}$ and $\binom{52}{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you draw k cards.

Then there are

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 52 \\k \end{pmatrix}$$

Ways to pick cards.

Of course the ways that don't count are

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 48 \\k \end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore

$$ 1 - \frac{\begin{pmatrix} 48 \\k \end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix} 52 \\k \end{pmatrix}} $$

Is the likelihood of getting at least one ace in drawing k cards. The case k = 5 corresponds to a traditional poker hand. k=2 corresponds to texas hold em. What you have put up isn't correct in that it doesn't fit the bill of conventional poker, unless we hypothetically played a 13 card game.

Comment: Thanks, I never played poker :)